# How do I get part of string between specific characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

How do I get  `006D`  from this string (It is a string, not a list):  `['006D','Model Name 6']` ?. Or, more generally, how do I get any string from between two characters like after`['`  and before  `',`?

I have heard of using the method `isDigit()`, ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)) but there are several strings like above mentioned where there are digits and characters as part of a hex representation. Thanks.

Comment: That's not a string, it's a list.

Comment: Please include some more sample inputs & expected outputs along with the code snippet you have tried.

Comment: in pyqt5 I used listWidget.currentItem() thats returns  ['006D','Model Name 6'] as a string. I have updated my question please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
string =  "['006D','Model Name 6']"
print(string.split("'")[1])
```

output:

```
006D
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I updated my Question . This line  ['006D','Model Name 6'] is not a list but i get this as a string from Pyqt5  listwidget.currentItem() that returns this line as a string.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your clarification that it was a string, not a list

Comment: Thanks that worked. my reputation is less than 15 so , couldn't upvote. I will try to learn the whole ```string.split()``` method that you mentioned. Thanks again.

Comment: Great! Mark the question as answered if you can so people know. FYI, the split method just separates a text string by a given delimiter, in this case its the the ' in between the " " marks. The string output returns a list, which you can then index into using [1] (or whatever the appropriate index position you are looking for)

Answer (score 1):

I have used @footfalcon 's solution. But I also found   `print(string[2:6])` works just fine. It outputs as expected `006D` .

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer your question as I interpret it, but it's a little unclear. You can let me know if I misunderstood you:

First, a string in Python is a set of characters like `"abcd123"` or `"Hi, I'm bob"`. What you have in our question is called a `list`, which is a collection of objects that might be strings or anything else (like numbers!).

So, to answer the question in the title **"How to get part of a string between specific characters**:

One way is to use [Regular Expressions](https://regexone.com/) (check out the link for practice problems). Here's an example:

```
import re
text = "hi my name is [wesley] 123454443 'asdf', 'yeah okay' "
n = re.search(r"(?<=')\w*(?=')", text)
print(n.group(0))
```

Will yield the string `asdf`.

Here's a breakdown:

1. `(?<=')` means that the search match `\w` only if preceded by `'`.
2. `\w` means that you are looking for any alpha numeric character
3. `*` means you are looking for any number of repetitions of `\w`
4. `(?=')` means that the search will only match `\w` if it is followed by `'`

I suggest going through the exercises in the link to get more familiar. I myself am not the best at using 'regex', but I find that it comes in very handy from time to time.

Also, here are the docs for the `re` library. I find them cumbersome and not well written. But maybe they will be [helpful for you](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: hi, Thanks for your answer. I'll check the ```re``` library and  try to implement this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need the ouptut

```
006D
```

Try the following code:

```
a =  ['006D','Model Name 6']
b=a[0]
print(b)
```

Comment: I think the OP is. looking for a way to detect this and extract. Thats my assumption but you may be right that OP is just looking to extract the 0th position.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one hex digit in a string, you can use this logic.

```
#create a string that represents  the hex string
#you could replace this with whatever you want
hex_check = '0123456789abcdefABCDEF'

#this will be your input string
your_string = "['006D','Model Name 6']"

#looks like each hex value is within single quotes
#split the input string at each value of '
temp = your_string.split("'")

#use a list comprehension to iterate and check if each set is a hex digit
hex_values = [i for i in temp if all(j in hex_check for j in i)]

#hex_values will be stored into a list. print the list
print (hex_values)
```

Comment: Hi, Noted your answer. Maybe i'll be use your method if i have multiple hex codes in a string. Thanks :)